# How to set global $wpdb in class variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use OOP in wordpress. Sample code below. As you can see I have to put `global $wpdb` in each method.  I want to avoid duplicating this line in each method.

Is there a way to set this in constructor or into some protected/private variable so i don't have to put that in every function?

```
    class HouseRepository {
        public function functionB() {
            global $wpdb;

            $results = $wpdb->get_results();

            return $results;
        }

        public function functionA() {
            global $wpdb;

            $results = $wpdb->get_results();

            return $results;
        }
    }
```

I tried doing in constructor (and removed from each method) it doesn't work.

```
function __construct() {
    global $wpdb;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting a reference to the `global $wpdb` variable to a class property or static property.

```
function __construct() {
    global $wpdb;

    $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    // or
    self::$wpdb = $wpdb;
}
```

And later access that property inside the methods.

```
public function functionA() {


    $results = $this->wpdb->get_results();
    // or
    $results = self::$wpdb->get_results();

    return $results;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Oh thats what i wanted. Thanks :D